# Mysql password with pound failing

Tags: mysql

For some reason the following password for a user will not work (for me) (remote server to server connection). However replace the £ with a _ and it works fine. Is this a mysql bug or encoding issue with my users table?

```
select PASSWORD('jnB£!dDwl8462lKi_')
```

You will see a value which is stored in the DB fine but try and connect and it fails with Access denied for user.

Comment: It says "Access denied for user using password YES"? Or is it another error message; as I noticed you're connecting remotely.

Comment: The error reads "ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'my_user'@IP (using password: YES)". I think the issue is that if you just run that query, you see the A^ (sorry don't know the correct key) before the £ so it must be an encoding thing but you don't normally define an encoding for the mysql.user table.

Comment: Try doing `PASSWORD( CONVERT('jnB£!dDwl8462lKi_' USING utf8) )`. IIRC, the default collation is latin1_swedish_ci (cp1252 west european)

Comment: Good thought but unfortunately not. I guess mysql must pass the password incorrectly during the connection.

Comment: I tested this here with your exact password example, and it works fine on MySQL 5.5.35 & 5.6.20 on OSX.  Works fine, I'd suggest testing the MySQL CLI client, it may be an issue with whatever client you are using.